# html popup window in simplekml

Tags: python, html, google-earth, simplekml

Say I have an html table:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What is the easiest/best way to insert that html bit into a kml popup window with the python package simplekml?

Answer (score 1):

Just found it. Description and [balloonstyle](http://simplekml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html?highlight=balloonstyle#simplekml.BalloonStyle) accept Html tags.

```
kml = simplekml.Kml(open=0) # open a file
pfol = kml.newfolder(name='foo',open=0) # start a folder
pol = pfol.newpoint(name= 'bar') # define a point
pol.balloonstyle.text = '<HTMLTABLE>' # insert html
pol.description = 'my point'
```